# What does 참코 애발매일 mean?

Tags: korean-to-english, phrase-meaning

So I’m trying to join a silent chat room and it requires a passcode. The passcode hint is ‘참코 애발매일 YYMMDD’. What does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had no clue at first sight. Searched up a bit to figure it out.

> “참코: 애 발매일.”

- **참코**: **참**가<sub>參加 joining</sub> **코**드<sub>code</sub>; passcode required to join.
- **애**: the name of the [Stray Kids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stray_Kids)’ digital single “[*Mixtape:**애***](https://youtu.be/M7lIml8-eHU).”
- **발매일**: 발매<sub>發賣 release</sub>-일<sub>日 date</sub>; release date.

> “**Passcode hint** — the release date of the Stray Kids’ digital single ‘*Mixtape:애*.’”

Which is June 26, 2021. It’s `210626`. There you go. Good luck with your K-pop journey.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I was getting tired of searching for a translation, but really thank you so much I was able to join it now <3

Answer (score 1):

1. 참코 애 -> no clue.
2. 발매일 YYMMDD -> release date YYMMDD

First part of the phrase means nothing. Some jargon maybe. You would have to figure out by yourself.